# CTAS with function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a table with the following columns: age(VARCHAR2), bothsexes(NUMBER), male(NUMBER), female(NUMBER). I am trying to write a CTAS statement using a stored function that will return a percentage (num1/num2). For the life of me, I cannot figure this out. essentially I want the CTAS to give me a second table with age(VARCHAR2) and percent(number), with each record from table 1 age being copied with the appropriate calculation for the percent.

This is what I have so far.

Here is my function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CALCULATE_PERCENT(NUM1 IN NUMBER,NUM2 IN NUMBER)
  RETURN NUMBER
    IS TOTAL NUMBER;
    BEGIN
      SELECT (NUM1/NUM2) INTO TOTAL FROM DUAL;
      RETURN TOTAL;
    END;
```

Here is my CTAS so far.

```
CREATE TABLE ARMalePercentage (AGE PRIMARY KEY) 
AS SELECT A.AGE, calculate_percent(num1=>A.MALE,num2=>A.BOTHSEXES) 
 "Percent Male Population" from arkansas2010census a;
```

I am new to SQL and have no clue what I'm doing wrong, so any help is appreciated.

Solution:

`CREATE TABLE ARMalePercentage (AGE PRIMARY KEY, "Percent Male Population") AS SELECT A.AGE, (select calculate_percent(a.MALE,a.BOTH_SEXES) from dual) "Percent Male Population" FROM arkansas2010census a;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a table `ARMalePercentage`  with *one* column, named `AGE`, that has a primary key constraint, and trying to populate it with a query that returns *two* columns, `A.AGE` and the results of your function.

I think you want

```
CREATE TABLE ARMalePercentage (AGE PRIMARY KEY, PCT_MALE) 
   AS SELECT A.AGE, 
      calculate_percent(num1=>A.MALE,num2=>A.BOTHSEXES) "Percent Male Population"
      from arkansas2010census a;
```

You can just try running the `SELECT` part of the statement to see you are getting back two columns.

Comment: I'm so dumb sometimes. It just clicked all of a sudden. Posting my solution up top. Thank you for spurring my brain!!

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to create a Table  just to see the calculated columns. Rather create a `VIEW`.

Your function can be simplified.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculate_percent (
     num1   IN NUMBER,
     num2   IN NUMBER
) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC --marks a function that returns predictable results
     IS
BEGIN
 RETURN ROUND( ( num1 / num2 ) * 100.00,2); --Optional rounding to 2 decimal places
END;
/
```

**View**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW armalepercentage AS
     SELECT a.age,
            calculate_percent(a.male,a.bothsexes) AS  "Percent Male Population"
     FROM arkansas2010census a;
```

Or simply add a [**`VIRTUAL COLUMN`**](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1) to the existing table

```
ALTER TABLE arkansas2010census ADD (
     PCT_MALE NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( calculate_percent(male,both_sexes) )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the virtual column approach; I was going to add that but didn't have time.  Only disadvantage of that is if that function would be used in other queries too, you would have duplicate code.

Comment: You could also add `result_cache` to the `deterministic` clause of the function definition; then when the function gets called with the second time with the same inputs, it won't even invoke the PL/SQL engine.